# How to run script with root privilege from web service on apache

Tags: php, apache, root

I must run a python script with root privilege from php webservice

```
$telephoneNumber = $_REQUEST["telephoneNumber"];
$textMessage = $_REQUEST["textMessage"];

$command = "sudo python /home/frank/Desktop/Main.py singular $telephoneNumber \"$textMessage\"";
system($command, $output);

$outVO->setOutcome(1);
$outVO->setDescription($output);

return $outVO;
```

but the proprietary of web service is www-data, so doesn't work

Comment: Please be aware that this is horrifyingly dangerous code. Imagine if someone submits a number or message like `\"; sudo rm -rf /;`

Comment: In my opinion it is not dangerous because the number and text are simple strings that will be passed to a GSM module that deals with sending a sms

Comment: You are mistaken. If the user includes a `;` (or uses various other tricks) the following text will not be passed as an argument to your Python script but will be evaluated by the shell as a separate command. Even if you restrict `sudo` to specific commands, a malicious user could still do undesirable things. Read the warnings in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).

Comment: You're absolutely right!!!

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues you are having is that you are attempting to reach a file in a home directory.  You should have both of the files in your working directory to make this easier.

Comment: While this may not be ideal, it's not going to keep this code from working.

Comment: It may not if the permissions are an issue (in which case he wants sudo).  But if the answer I have provided is not sufficient, then the potential for nefarious use is possible.